# Are large scale wire wound resistors used?

Tags: resistors

I have many different large wire wound resistors. Are they still in use? It is 71.0 Ohms, tests at 72.3. Are they obsolete?[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Anybody can use a resistor, I don't know who would use this specifically but you might check on sites with similar items and see if someone would want it. It's really the wattage that is important and how much current it can handle.

Comment: I cant find them online

Comment: Large resistors come off handy from time to time, in particular as dummy loads. And high power resistors are quite expensive (but still far less expensive than a programmable load). So if you sell them cheap enough, I expect you will find someone to buy them. The power rating however is as important as the the resistance value. If you can't find it out, then it strongly decreases the interest (because you will have to be very conservative).

Comment: Ceramic power resistor with an adjustable tap. There are still uses for them.

Comment: I discovered it is 2.2 AMPS.

Comment: https://www.partssupercenter.com/docs/default-source/product-catalogs/drives/gep-345e-resistors.pdf?sfvrsn=75d5a641_2

Comment: Still useful if you need the power handling and don't mind the self-inductance (so not RF applications).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're still used in some applications. That particular part could be used as an adjustable load in the low hundreds of watts, however for a maximum of about 155VDC or 155VAC RMS. In fact, I rather suspect the oddball  71Ω standard value was chosen to be useful on 120VAC/60Hz North American mains voltage.

They would not be all that useful for lower voltages such as 24V (maximum power only 53W so most of the capacity would be wasted). A lower element resistance would be indicated for such applications.